# Is there a way to make VirtualBox use a specific monitor when going full-screen?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, fullscreen

I am running VirtualBox on a dual-monitor Windows 7 x64 system. When I put a VM into full-screen mode it always appears full-screen on my primary monitor even though the VM window was on the secondary monitor. Is there a way to make it appear full-screen on the secondary monitor?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you are in Full Screen mode in the view menu choose "Virtual Screen 1", "Use Host Screen 2"

While in fullscreen mode, press **HostKey + Home** to bring up the hidden menu.
Select View -> "Virtual Screen 1" -> "Use Host Screen 2"

Comment: Really late to comment, but is it possible to make 'Host Screen 2' the default one?

Comment: @ChethanS. That's done in windows settings.

Comment: So for some reason, this fix didn't work in Full Screen mode for me, but in Seamless mode (my normal mode), using the view menu with this fix did the trick. Thanks!